# File name with slash

Tags: c++, filenames

In my program, I want to save file in current directory. File contains web page content and should be called as `url`, from where it has been downloaded. For example, if url is `http://some.url/some-article`, so file should be named *"some.url/some-article.txt"*. I trying something like:

```
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(fileName, std::ios::out);
```

It works perfectly, but when slash appears in fileName, file isn't created. I tried to escape slash (with '\'), but it does not work. Is it possible to save file with slashes in name?

**Note: I want to name files like urls. I don't want to create directories.**

Comment: [You can't have a file name with `/` in the name.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)

Comment: @Leiaz Depends on the operating system. OS X for instance allows this (and encodes it internally as `:` which is really confusing). But yeah, it’s a **very** bad idea.

Comment: @farvel, what you have as an OS?

Comment: no, this is not  duplicate to what you designed

Comment: @bigOTHER, crossplatform, including windows

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph now i undestood... So, what do you fink is best delimiter instead of '\'?

Comment: @farvel Well you *could* use subfolders. Otherwise, how about `_` or `-`?